# Swift Image Filter

Tags: swift, image, filter, core-image

The filtering on the photo works but I'm stuck with this problem.

---

### When I run this code:

```
let originalImage = CIImage(image: imageView.image)

var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectMono")

filter.setDefaults()
filter.setValue(originalImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

var newImage = UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage)
imageView.image = newImage
```

---

### **The first error is:**

`BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted`

---

### **The second error is:**

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

---

Then the app crashes.

How would I fix it and the errors?

Comment: On which line does the program crash?

Comment: Set up a breakpoint on the UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage) line and step over, check for nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I Found A Solution:

**Updated**

```
let originalImage = CIImage(image: imageView.image)
var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectMono")
filter.setValue(originalImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let context = CIContext(options: [kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: true])
let outputImage = context.createCGImage(filter.outputImage, fromRect: filter.outputImage.extent())
var newImage = UIImage(CGImage: outputImage)
imageView.image = newImage
```

*Based on **Lamar's** code.

---

`CIContext(options: nil)` was causing `BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted` error.

**SO replace:**

`CIContext(options: nil)` with `CIContext(options: [kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: true])`

---

Thanks For The Help:

**Lamar**

The app doesn't crash anymore.

Comment: Maybe you should reset your simulator

Comment: Are you using swift 2.0 because that's the first time I see this error. Maybe you should **try catch error**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let originalImage = CIImage(image: imageView.image)
var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectMono")
 filter.setValue(originalImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let context = CIContext(options:nil)
let ouputImage = context.createdCGImage(filter,fromRect:filter.extend())
 var newImage = UIImage(CGImage: ouputImage)
   imageView.image = newImage
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs fine. Your image source imageView.image is probably nil when you call it. You can try this at playground:

```
let myPicture = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!)!)!

let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectMono")
filter.setValue(CIImage(image: myPicture), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let newImage = UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**I have added Black n White Effect To an Image** 

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(clickedImage.bounds.size)
                clickedImage.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
                var image2: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                origionalimage=image2;
                var CIfilterName = "CIPhotoEffectTonal"
                let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
                let startImage = CIImage(image: image2)
                let filter = CIFilter(name: CIfilterName)
                filter.setDefaults()
                filter.setValue(startImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
                let filteredImageData = filter.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
                let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, fromRect: filteredImageData.extent())
                var newImage = UIImage(CGImage: filteredImageRef)!
                self.mediaData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage )
                self.videoThumbData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, 0.1)
                self.clickedImage.image = newImage;
```